# Calculate Minimum Distance of all Rows Fulfilling Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas in python and want to do the following:
I want to introduce a new column A in my dataframe. For calculating it I want to consider all rows which have in column B the same value as my "current element" (I think that's a part where im stuck right now) in column B, and then take the minimum value of column C minus the value of the current element of C of all these - and exclude the difference 0, namely a self-reference.

As an example:

```
   B  C    A
0  0  1.2  1.7  (calculation: possible rows are 1 and 2 (all have B = 0), the differences are 2.9 - 1.2 and 3.0 - 1.2 => min = 1.7
1  0  2.9  -1.7 (min difference is 1.2 - 2.9)
2  0  3.0  -1.8
3  1  4.1  1.4
4  1  5.5  -1.4
```

Thank you!

Comment: What I wrote so far is: `df.apply(lambda x: df[(df.B == x.B) & (~df.C.eq(x.C))].min().C - x.C, axis=1)' This works as required, however I have two issuse: checking that df.C == x.C just works in this example (so how do I exclude my current elements really without just checking for one column), plus apply is slow right? Any better ways?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit to handle new dataset:

```
df.groupby('B')['C'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x.idxmin() == x.index,
                                                  x.nsmallest(2).iloc[1]-x,
                                                  (x[x.idxmin()] - x)))
```

Output:

```
   B    C    A  A_new
0  0  1.2  1.7    1.7
1  0  2.9 -1.7   -1.7
2  0  3.0 -1.8   -1.8
3  1  4.1  1.4    1.4
4  1  5.5 -1.0   -1.4
```

IIUC, think you want this, however I am not sure about the 1 in column A.  This is the first row in each group.  I replace the 0 with 1.

```
df['A_new'] = df.groupby('B')['C'].transform(lambda x: (x[x.idxmin()] - x).replace(0,1))
```

Output:

```
   B  C  A  A_new
0  0  1  1      1
1  0  2 -1     -1
2  0  3 -2     -2
3  1  4  1      1
4  1  5 -1     -1
```

Timings:

Your solution:

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: df[(df.B == x.B) & (~df.C.eq(x.C))].min().C - x.C, axis=1)
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 9.78 ms per loop

This solution:

```
%timeit df.groupby('B')['C'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x.idxmin() == x.index,1,(x[x.idxmin()] - x)))
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 3.58 ms per loop

Comment: Cool, thank you! This is exactly what I meant. However you also have to replace 0 by 1 since you don't check if the elements are equal, right? Which is a little downside. Also, is your approach using transform faster than my with apply (see my comment above)?

Comment: Yes. This is one way of doing it.  When the elements are equal, then replace 0 with 1.  No need for the extra check.  The check is built in to the calcuation, just do a replace at the end.

Comment: @Gemini May this is more accurate for you: `df.groupby('B')['C'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x.idxmin() == x.index,1,(x[x.idxmin()] - x)))` check to see if the index of the current element is equal to the index of the minimum element.  This will only work if there id only one minimum value of C in each group.  The previous solution will replace all min values with 1.

Comment: This works, but unforunately my dataset is huge so this takes a long time .. I would prefer something without apply / transform ...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info! I see your approach is faster, nice. However, a factor of 3 will not really help me .. so I will wait a bit more to see if a vectorized answer can be found.

Comment: @Gemini if this solution helped yo would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand , but work ...

```
df['new'] = df.B.map(df.groupby('B').C.apply(list))

df.apply(lambda x :min(list(map(lambda y: y - x['C'],list(set(x['new'])-set([x['C']]))))),axis=1)


Out[1013]: 
0    1
1   -1
2   -2
3    1
4   -1
dtype: int64
```

More info :

```
df['NewA']=df.apply(lambda x :min(list(map(lambda y: y - x['C'],list(set(x['new'])-set([x['C']]))))),axis=1)
df
Out[1015]: 
   B  C  A        new  NewA
0  0  1  1  [1, 2, 3]     1
1  0  2 -1  [1, 2, 3]    -1
2  0  3 -2  [1, 2, 3]    -2
3  1  4  1     [4, 5]     1
4  1  5 -1     [4, 5]    -1
```

---

Let us using numpy approach

```
A = df.C.values[:, None] - df.C.values.T
np.fill_diagonal(A, 9999999)
G=df.groupby('B')
np.concatenate([np.min(A[y.min():y.max()+1,y.min():y.max()+1],0) for _, y in G.groups.items()])
```

Time

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: df[(df.B == x.B) & (~df.C.eq(x.C))].min().C - x.C, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.14 ms per loop
%timeit df.groupby('B')['C'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x.idxmin() == x.index,1,(x[x.idxmin()] - x)))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop

def fff(x):
    A = df.C.values[:, None] - df.C.values.T
    np.fill_diagonal(A, 9999999)
    G=df.groupby('B')
    np.concatenate([np.min(A[y.min():y.max()+1,y.min():y.max()+1],0) for _, y in G.groups.items()])
%timeit fff(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 758 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but unforunately my dataset is huge so this takes a long time .. I would prefer something without apply / transform ...

Comment: @Gemini yoou have different group in your data right ?

Comment: what do you mean by that? C can be any arbitrary value yes

Comment: @Gemini I mean you have different group data by B

Comment: sorry, still dont understand. but there are many different values of B yes

Answer (score 1):

Transform min and subtract `C`

```
df['new'] = (df.groupby('B')['C'].transform('min')-df['C']).replace(0,1)

   B  C  A  new
0  0  1  1    1
1  0  2 -1   -1
2  0  3 -2   -2
3  1  4  1    1
4  1  5 -1   -1
```

Edit based on updated dataframe :

```
g = df.groupby('B')
diff = g['C'].transform('min') - df['C']
df['new'] = diff.where(diff!=0,np.nan)
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(df['new'].abs().groupby(df['B']).transform('min'))

  B    C    A  new
0  0  1.2  1.7  1.7
1  0  2.9 -1.7 -1.7
2  0  3.0 -1.8 -1.8
3  1  4.1  1.4  1.4
4  1  5.5 -1.4 -1.4
```

Comment: You assuming the increment of C are 1 ?

Comment: change C to 2,1,100,2,5

Comment: I am curious too, unfortunately I do not understand it. C can have any arbitrary (float) value

Comment: @Gemini try the vectorized solution which is a thousand times faster than using lambda

Comment: I would love to, however I don't know how. I fear your code is not doing what I want but just works on the toy example given the Cs?

Comment: Now I did. This is a very intersting start, but unfortunately not quite what I am looking for I believe. Since now you just caluclate the minimum of C and then substract the current value. However, the replace (0, 1) is not helpful in my case, as I am dealing with coordinates. I really want to exclude the "current element" .. cant wrap my head around how to do that right now ... Hope I am making myself clear

Comment: Except the row with min you want to subtract with other elements? Am I correct?

Comment: So I really want the min of the difference, not the min of C

Comment: I changed my original example, does that help?

Comment: But as a workaround it would be also okay (although its not super nice) to ignore differences with value 0 (so not using replace 0, 1 but doing sth else)

Comment: @Gemini adding the numpy approach

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the helpful answers.
My prefered solution now is this:

```
res = df.sort_values(['B', 'C'])
res.loc[res.B.eq(res.shift(1).B), 'A'] = res.C - res.shift(1).C
df = pd.merge(df, res, on=['B', 'C'])
```

What do you think?
So then I get all smaller / bigger values and could merge those.